# Omniauth with Linkedin Oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to add linkedin registration options to my devise sign-up page.

I'm trying to follow these instructions: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

and this tutorial: http://www.slideshare.net/KamyarMohager/o-auth-2-and-linked-inpdf

but am getting stuck on this step: Generate Authorization Code by redirecting user to LinkedIn's authorisation dialog

Where do i put the redirect code? Does it go in omniauth callbacks controller?

Can anyone point me to step by step instructions for setting this up?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having, that Railscasts, LinkedIn developer documentation and other blogs did not answer for me was that if you're using omniauth, you skip step 3 of the LinkedIn developer documents. The answer is don't worry about it.

Then, when you're registering your app in LinkedIn's application, the callback url is what you get when you run rake routes on your app. The route for your callbacks controller is the URL that LinkedIn needs to match to.

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much for posting an answer. I actually found another tutorial that helped me figure out how to configure linkedin. I dont want to mark this with a tick because I couldn't follow it to get the app working. I really appreciate your trying to help though. Cheers,

Comment: If you found a better solution, could you kindly link to it?

Comment: Hi - sorry - I should have done that when I posted my first response. I can't remember where I found it now. I'm sorry not to have shared the link.